Python 3 superclass instantiation via derived class's default constructor
In this code:
class A():
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.x

class B(A):
  def __str__(self):
    return super().__str__()

b = B("Hi")
print(b)

The output is: Hi.
What is happening under the hood? How does the default constructor in the derived class invoke the super class constructor? How are the params passed to the derived class object get mapped to those of the super class?

there is no default constructor. All methods are inherited. If you hadn't defined one in A, it would use object.__init__, which does nothing


How does the default constructor in the derived class invoke the super class constructor?

You didn't override it in B, so you inherited it from A. That's what inheritance is for.
>>> B.__init__ is A.__init__
True

In the same vein, you may as well not define B.__str__ at all here, since it doesn't do anything (other than add a useless extra frame into the call stack).

How are the params passed to the derived class object get mapped to those of the super class?

You may be overthinking this. As shown above, B.__init__ and A.__init__ are identical. B.__init__ gets resolved in the namespace of A, since it is not present in the namespace of B.
>>> B.__mro__
(__main__.B, __main__.A, object)
>>> A.__dict__["__init__"]
<function __main__.A.__init__(self, x)>
>>> B.__dict__["__init__"]
...
# KeyError: '__init__'


What is happening under the hood?

Please note that __init__ methods are not constructors. If you're looking for an analogy of constructors in other programming languages, the __new__ method may be more suitable than __init__. First, an instance of B will created (by __new__), and then this instance will be passed as the first positional argument self to A.__init__, along with the string value "Hi" for the second positional argument x.

Do you think it's worth mentioning how B("hi") invokes type.__call__(B, "hi")? I'm not sure how much of a rabbit hole OP really wants to go down.

@chepner I don't think it's worth mentioning unless metaclasses (other than type) are involved. If you do, feel free to edit in details.

I'll post a separate answer; it's ugly enough that I don't think it's worth cluttering your more straightforward one.

Thanks for the detailed answer @wim. Learnt a lot.

First, what does it mean to call B in the first place? B is an instance of type, and instances are callable when their classes define __call__. type.__call__ can be thought of as being defined as
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.__new__(self, *args, **kawrgs)
    if isinstance(obj, self):
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj

So B("hi") starts as a call to type.__call__(B, "hi").
Inside __call__, we first try to call B.__new__(B, "hi"). Since B.__new__ is not defined, we need to look at B's method resolution order to find a class that does define __new__.
>>> B.__mro___
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)

A does not, but object does, so we end up with
obj = object.__new__(B, "hi")

which effectively ignores "hi" and returns a "bare" instance of B (the first argument). *
Since obj is indeed an instance of B, isinstance returns True and we call the __init__ method. Once again, obj has no __init__ attribute, so we fall back to the method resolution order of type(obj) to find one, and we find A.__init__. So we execute A.__init__(obj, "hi") before finally returning obj.

* There is a small amount of "magic" that I'm not aware of. object.__new__ can raise a TypeError if it receives arguments that it is not expecting:
>>> object.__new__(object, "hi")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object() takes no arguments

so I'm not sure exactly how object.__new__(B, "hi") works. As far as I can tell, the existence of an __init__ method for the first argument is sufficient to make object.__new__ accept and ignore arbitrary arguments.
